# HTML, Angular Js and Css for ecommerce website development

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova

Currently we are developing a ecommerce webapplications in asp.net and now we are planning to move to new architecture for a better performance and it should support hybrid mobile app using cordova.

We are planning to develop Ui with HTML, Angular Js and Css and Asp.net MVC WebAPIs for server side.

We have done lot of R & D and discussing about architecture. We thought this is the right place to get the right answer.

Please clarify below points

1) In ecom, we need maintain a basket details before login and the same basket to be available to the user after login. So how do we maintain the basket as a session concept in asp.net

2) In ecom, We have 30 to 40 pages will be there. so how do we incorporate the same with Angular as we know that angular suitable for single page applications

3) Do we require more javascript expertise in development team.

4) How do we maintain the security about the loggedin user information.
5) How do we solve issues with angular js like cross site scripting, hacking, session fixation etc...

Comment: I think it would be better for you to setup a research document and research every single element yourself instead of asking it on StackOverflow. The question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't know how much you need to know, but about the session, asp.net accept casting in sessions, like Session["basket"] as BasketViewModel or something like that. So if you put your basket information in a Session and you can retrieve it later as I said before.

2)It depends how you plain to structure your application, if you want to create the system complete SPA, you can use routes and partials presents in angular.

3)AngularJs needs a good understanding in JS, specially if you want to develop a ecommerce.

4)Most people like to use Token authentication when dealing with SPA application. if you look for AngularJS Token Authentication you going to find a lot of resource about it and how it works.

5)Angular comes with a library called sanitize, that helps in some of this issues...since it's a client side app, the heavy part about security is placed on the restapi...

hope it helps